# Content Size becomes smaller after adding a segue in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am in the middle of attempting to create an iOS app. It has two screens at the moment, between which I am attempting to add a segue.

However, when I add a segue (no matter what type of segue I add) the second screen's content shifts down by 54 pixels. This includes the background (to which I tried adding constraints, it still shifts down), the Safe Area, and the UI content of the second screen. All of it shifts downward by 54 pixels immediately upon adding a segue. When I check the attributes panel to try to identify the problem, it says Screen One's Content Size is 414 x 896 ...these numbers are there automatically and were not altered manually and Content Size is unchecked.

However, for Screen Two's Content Size - after adding the segue - it says 414 x 842. These numbers are also there automatically and were not altered manually and Content Size is unchecked. (Before adding the segue, the Content Size for both screens was identical and were placed there automatically, Content Size unchecked).

This means this isn't just a matter of the content shifting downward upon adding a segue - but instead an issue of the Content Size becoming 56 pixels smaller upon adding a segue (this includes the safe area).

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to prevent this?

Comment: Kindly add few sample of code you have, specifically where you thing the error is from.

Comment: There is no code in my project yet. This is purely all placement of UI elements so far into the project. I haven't begun to code it yet.